# Gulp Task does not include subfolders

Tags: gulp, eslint

I'm trying to set up a Gulp task for eslint (System: OS Windows 10). But it seems that the src is not being evaluated correctly:

```
gulp.task('lint-app-basic-an', function() {
    gulp.src('src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint({
            configFile: '.eslintrc.js'
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

There are several subfolders underneath src/main/webapp/app-basic-an, e.g.

```
src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/components/page-header/page-header.component.js
```

If I create a lint error in said JS-File, it is ignored by the linter. If I specify the path 1 level more in the tasks .src-function like

```
gulp.src('src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/components/**/*.js')
```

It suddenly works, which makes no sense to me, I thought "**/" meant zero or more subdirectories?

Comment: You should return the stream, otherwise gulp does not know it should wait (i.e. add `return gulp.src('...`).

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Though I don't understand why... Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp executes its tasks in an asynchronous manner. For gulp to be able to know that some task has finished, the tasks needs to do [one of the following](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps-fn):

- return stream (e.g. the one created by `gulp.src`) on which gulp can listen [for `end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end),
- return `q` promise or
- call callback function passed as task function argument

If the task does not accept arguments and does not return promise or stream, gulp considers that task synchronous (i.e. it is finished once the function call returns). Once all tasks are finished, the execution stops... hence if you have some async processing, it will never finish (or worse - it might end at a random point).

Comment: Thanks! But that does not explain why `gulp.src('src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/**/*.js')` does not work, but `gulp.src('src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/components/**/*.js')` does, am I right? That is weird to me.... Still, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You would need to dig deep inside the *glob stream* and *orchestrator* implementations to know the answers. As I wrote - without proper async handling the behaviour is undefined and you are in the realm of race conditions (*"Will the tool exit before or after some folder is processed?"*).